# Add a Webpack 'loader' to `polymer build`

Tags: polymer, polymer-3.x, polymer-cli

Is there any way to add a Webpack loader to Polymer 3.0's build and serve CLI?

I'm familiar with using Webpack to build Polymer apps, but not with the Polymer CLI — I didn't find a public interface, but I didn't look for long.

Comment: Maybe taking a look at [https://github.com/web-padawan/polymer3-webpack-starter](https://github.com/web-padawan/polymer3-webpack-starter) will  help

Comment: Thanks, for no, that's the easy bit I'm familiar with. I shall have to venture into the source....